# Letting a GridLayout Set Its Own Number of Columns

Tags: android, button, scrollview, grid-layout

I'm adding a certain number of buttons to a `GridLayout` and I don't want to set a specific column amount (because when I do that and the phone's orientation is changed, things don't look good). I've tried taking out the column specification, but that just results in it having 1 non-ending row.

I'm looking to have the buttons be the same size and have them fill out the empty space as available. I'm not interested in stretching the width of the buttons.

**Java**:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_grid);
for(int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(i+"");
    gridLayout.addView(button);
}
```

**XML** (I'm wrapping the `GridLayout` in a `ScrollView` because I'm anticipating the buttons will run off the screen vertically):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".Grid" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a simple `GridView` with its `numColumns` attribute set to `auto_fit`. It will also take care of the scrolling for you so you can remove the `ScrollView`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:numColumns

Comment: While that's very useful (and I've tried it), I can't make `GridView `take new buttons on the Java side. I tried doing `someGridView.addView(someButton)` and `GridView` doesn't have that method available. Do you know how I can add `View` objects to `Gridview`?

Comment: Add them to the `Adapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure which `Adapter` you're referring to and how to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Could you please give me a piece of example code?